# Как написать бота на discord.py который будет ставить реакцию на все сообщения определённого пользователя?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Нужно что бы на любое сообщение одного пользователя бот ставил реакцию, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Погуглите и приходите с конкретными вопросами. Приложите свой код и покажите что не получается. Мы не будем делать за Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```py
client = discord.Client()
whiteList = [123123123123123123, 
             155149108183695360, 
             235088799074484224] # ID пользователей кому ставить реакции 
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id in whiteList:
        await message.add_reaction('')
```

[Документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message)